# Protecting Facebook API Secret in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Given that C# can be decompiled incredibly easily, exposing all set variables as well as functionality, is there a way I can fully protect the API Secret that Facebook provides for creating an App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to this problem is to store these credentials in your app.config file and then encrypting the section containing these credentials using DPAPI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

Decrypting config values is transparent and can still be done through the `ConfigurationManager` class.

Answer (score 3):

A general rule of software design is to not trust the client. Whatever the client can do, anyone can do. You can try some security by obscurity and have a method that does something to "generate" the secret or you can hide it away in a seemingly unrelated class, but at the end of the day, anyone with a little bit of time can just look at the outgoing packets and extract the key from that.

If you want real security, route all your networking through your server. Have the client send commands to your server, which will interpret the commands and use the Facebook API with your secret to send the client back the proper data.

Comment: And this isn't just for .NET languages or a language that can be decompiled easily. Yeah, it can be harder to *extract* the key from the program, but it's just as easy to view outgoing packets with wireshark and copy the API secret from there.

Comment: How about allowing the application to access the users profile after login. Wouldn't the program need to have it integrated so as to allow for the user to allow the application access to their settings? And what would need to be sent to authenticate the user?

Comment: If you have additional info to your own answer, it is better to edit the answer and add the info than commenting on it.

Comment: If the application is a WinForms application, there would be no server. Are you saying it is impossible to create a client winforms application that both uses the facebook api and protects the API Secret?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that it's impossible to create **any** client that does both. And you can use a server with a winforms application. It would just never sends web requests to Facebook directly. You would purchase a domain name and create a simple program that would take requests to access the Facebook API from any client, make the actual API call, and send the resulting data from Facebook back to the client. The way the client is displayed doesn't matter, it could be an arduino with a small screen attached to it as long as it can send the right network commands to the server program.